# How to transfer file from Nokia E72 to a PC via WiFi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, file-transfer, nokia-e-series

I want to transfer a file to and from from a Nokia E72 to a laptop using WiFi. I am able to connect to WiFi using WLAN Wizard. But I don't know how to transfer a file to my laptop running Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize a free application called [Dukto](http://store.ovi.com/content/67131) to transfer files between your PC and smartphone. It's an open source project by Emanuele Colombo and works with Windows, OS X and Linux. You can download the installer for your PC [here](http://www.msec.it/blog/?page_id=11).

Answer (score 1):

I had an E71x that I used to use as my primary phone before replacing it last year. Is there a particular reason you want to use WiFi? I used Bluetooth to sync all the files on that phone to my computer (as well as do other things). I was able to browse the files and folders on the phone using ftp over Bluetooth and it worked great. Are you able to do something like that?

My computer didn't have Bluetooth so I got a USB to Bluetooth adapter for about $30 on Amazon. After installing the Nokia Ovi Suite software on my desktop (or laptop, as I used it on both), I was able to do anything I wanted to the phone from my computer, including file transfer and sync.